# How do I get the leaflet layer group ID?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I've got two layers in Leaflet. Each layer is a geoJSON map of the United States with 51 features.

I'm attaching an event handler on mouseout to both:

```
function resetHighlight(e, whichLayer) {
    if (whichLayer == terpsLayer) {
        console.log('reset');
        layerTerps.resetStyle(e.target);
    } else if (whichLayer == lawsLayer) {
        layerLaws.resetStyle(e.target);
    }
}

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
        mouseout: function(e) {
           resetHighlight(e, layer);
        }
    });
}
```

This is called in the typical `onEachFeature` function when creating the geoJSON layer.

I can't figure out how to get `whichLayer` to represent the geoJSON layer instead of one of the individual 51 features. If you, for example, click on a feature, how can you get Leaflet to identify which group layer it is from?

Answer (score 1):

You can call `hasLayer(layer)` to check in which layergroup your layer is.

```
layerGroup1 = new L.LayerGroup();
layerGroup2 = new L.LayerGroup();

function getLayerGroup(layer){
    if(layerGroup1.hasLayer(layer)){
        return layerGroup1;
    }else if(layerGroup2.hasLayer(layer)){
        return layerGroup2;
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create a LayerGroup and add both layers to it as follows:

```
layerGroup = new L.LayerGroup()
layerGroup.addLayer(Layer1)
layerGroup.addLayer(Layer2)
```

Then loop through the LayerGroup to get the layer Id and loop through each layer to get the feature Id like so:

```
layerGroup.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    const layerId = layerGroup.getLayerId(layer)
    layer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
        const FeatureId = layer.feature.properties.Id
    });
});
```